# Common Mark in Maven Pom

Tags: osgi, commonmark

I added this in the core pom:

```
        <groupId>org.commonmark</groupId>
        <artifactId>commonmark</artifactId>
        <version>0.17.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
```

and on deploying this, my bundle gets into installed state. If I try to activate my bundle, I get the below error:

```
org.apache.felix.log.LogException: org.osgi.framework.BundleException:
missing requirement 
  [mybundle.core [600](R 600.5)] osgi.wiring.package; 
  (osgi.wiring.package=org.commonmark.parser)] Unresolved requirements: [[mybundle.core 
  [609](R 609.0)] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=com.mybundle.core.exceptions) 
  (version>=1.0.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))]
```

`